# Jenkins sever startup issue

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have Jenkins server installed on a dedicated Jenkins machine(Windows 10). I was trying out something and in services, I have changed the "Logon As" from local System to my credentials. Since then I am unable to access Jenkins server, it shows the page with the content mentioned below

**Skip to content
[Jenkins]Jenkins
[Jenkins]Jenkins**

When i click on skip to content it shows the below error

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
  at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:142)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temporary file in 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins
  at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:144)
  at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:109)
  at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:84)
  at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.<init>(AtomicFileWriter.java:74)
  at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:189)
  at jenkins.model.Jenkins.save(Jenkins.java:3353)
  at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:987)
  at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
  at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
  at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
  at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

I also changed the "Logon As" in services to the one that was previously present i.e. "Local system". The issue still persists. After changing it to local system, when i manually start the service it automatically stops after few seconds.

Any help to retrieve the server back will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Sharan

Comment: Did you check the permission of C:\Program Files (x86)\jenkins ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Jenkins windows service need admin rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722510/does-jenkins-windows-service-need-admin-rights)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

After changing the "Logon As" in services to the one that was previously present i.e. "Local system" from my credentials, I restarted the system. I am now able to access the Jenkins server.